# Is there any way to get information of subscribed users using Google Play Developer API?

Tags: xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api, android-inapp-purchase

I'm linking IAP to Android WebApp developed with Xamarin.

I am receiving and processing a webhook for a subscription service through Pub/Sub, but I need to get the email information of the subscribed user using OrderId or PurchaseToken.

I got subscription information through purchases.subscriptions.get api of Google Play Developer API, but it does not return emailAddress, profileName, etc.

The documentation says that it will only be returned if you subscribed to ‘Subscribe with Google’.
No matter how much I search, I don't know what 'Subscribe with Google' means.

We are paying with Google Play IAP through our Google account, but values ​​such as emailAddress and profileName are not returned.

**I need your help. When a new payment webhook is received from the server, please tell me another way to get the e-mail information of the paying user.**

thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Subscribe with Google" (aka SwG) is a program dedicated to publishers (ie: newspapers). If your app doesn't belong to this group, you won't be able to have the information.

Moreover, even if you used SwG, you wouldn't have access to your users' emails when they subscribe through your app.

In other words, I don't think SwG will solve your problem since you wouldn't have access to your users' emails.

The only way to get them is by asking your users' emails **before** they subscribe **and then** send to your server this email + the purchase_token you get when they subscribe.